# force Apache2 to respond only on 1 specific URL and not any other

Tags: apache, virtualhost, restrict, phishing, a-records

I have multiple  A record  for the same server IP address, I mean:

```
URL            DNS res.
goodurl.com    10.0.0.1 
badurl1.com    10.0.0.1 
badurl2.com    10.0.0.1
```

I would like to configure Apache2 so that it works only with  URL goodurl.com and not with any other.

I've found the way to give "access denied" on specific URL "badurl1.com" like this :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName badurl1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory /var/www/>
            AllowOverride None
            Order deny,allow
            deny from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Is there a more elegant and efficent way to do the same?**

**Is there a way to configure Apache to be sure that any other future and undesired new A record,  will be rejected by default?**

thanks in advance for your help

```
system SO:      Linux 2.6.32-5-amd64  x86_64 GNU/Linux
Server version: Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
```

Answer (score 2):

A friend suggested me to add this at the bottom of the config file. It works as I expected.

The trick is to create a (pseudo)random ServerName and to give an "*"  as ServerAlias.

This way it matches my correct config for the ServerName and ServerAlias  I've configured at the top and fallback on "fail" dir (with no access rights) for all other URLs poiting to my IP.

```
lupo@pippo:/var/www# mkdir fail
lupo@pippo:/var/www# chmod -R 000 fail

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName goodurl.com
    ServerAlias     www.goodurl.com goodurl
........
........
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  lkfjLKJfiu90FJIDSNMFLKSDFMLKSDJNFLKSDFHIDOFH89DFY89NNS
    ServerAlias *
    DocumentRoot /var/www/fail
    <Directory /var/www/fail/>
            AllowOverride None
            Order deny,allow
            deny from all
    </Directory>


</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use dynamic virtual host. Essentially the path name will contain the virtual host server name, so that if the path does not exist, the server will return file not found.

```
<VirtualHost 111.22.33.44>
    ServerName                 customer-1.example.com
    DocumentRoot        /www/hosts/customer-1.example.com/docs
    ScriptAlias  /cgi-bin/  /www/hosts/customer-1.example.com/cgi-bin
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 111.22.33.44>
    ServerName                 customer-2.example.com
    DocumentRoot        /www/hosts/customer-2.example.com/docs
    ScriptAlias  /cgi-bin/  /www/hosts/customer-2.example.com/cgi-bin
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 111.22.33.44>
    ServerName                 customer-N.example.com
    DocumentRoot        /www/hosts/customer-N.example.com/docs
    ScriptAlias  /cgi-bin/  /www/hosts/customer-N.example.com/cgi-bin
</VirtualHost>
```

becomes

```
# get the server name from the Host: header
UseCanonicalName Off

# this log format can be split per-virtual-host based on the first field
# using the split-logfile utility.
LogFormat "%V %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b" vcommon
CustomLog logs/access_log vcommon

# include the server name in the filenames used to satisfy requests
VirtualDocumentRoot /www/hosts/%0/docs
VirtualScriptAlias  /www/hosts/%0/cgi-bin
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/mass.html